# jQuery/Javascript won't run on my server, local machine only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen a lot of these questions listed but none actually answered the questions.  I made a word cloud on a local machine and it worked like a charm.  I loaded it onto the server and now the scripts won't run.  I thought it might have to do with the src links but I even went so far as to put the full path in there and that didn't help at all.

here is the link to my page:  www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/wordcloud.html

Any thoughts or otherwise would be appreciated.  Below is the code for my script links:

```
<link REL = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src =     "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src = "www.johnverber.com/home/johnverb/public_html/wordcloud/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src = "www.johnverber.com/home/johnverb/public_html/wordcloud/tagtools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src = "www.johnverber.com/home/johnverb/public_html/wordcloud/openDocTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src = "www.johnverber.com/home/johnverb/public_html/wordcloud/executeTag.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your paths absolute.  Add the `http://` before all your script paths.  It would also appear that most (if not all) of your scripts are missing from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the net tab in the browser, you will see your urls are wrong.

```
GET http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/www.johnverber.com/home/johnverb/public_html/wordcloud/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) wordcloud.html:6
GET http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/www.johnverber.com/home/johnverb/public_html/wordcloud/tagtools.js 404 (Not Found) wordcloud.html:6
GET http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/www.johnverber.com/home/johnverb/public_html/wordcloud/openDocTools.js 404 (Not Found) wordcloud.html:6
GET http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/www.johnverber.com/home/johnverb/public_html/wordcloud/executeTag.js 404 (Not Found) wordcloud.html:6
```

Comment: `GET http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/tagtools.js 404 (Not Found) wordcloud.html:6`

Comment: Your new error is because you are using a feature of activex that requires different securtity settings.

Comment: Ok.  Do you know of somewhere I can read up on that by any chance? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add your page to trusted sites and it will work. Only way around it is to not use ActiveX and have the user upload the file to your server where you read it and give it to your page. Plus ActiveX is IE only so you are shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 1):

Your script paths are wrong, remove the `home/johnverb/public_html/` part and include the protocol i.e. `http://` if you are using absolute paths

```
http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/jquery.js
http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/openDocTools.js
http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/executeTag.js
http://www.johnverber.com/wordcloud/tagtools.js[404 not found]
```

Comment: Fixed the paths. It is saying that I the server cannot create an object in reference to:

   fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

Comment: You might want to open a new question for that one